# Why is takeWhile stateful?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) states that

> This is a short-circuiting **stateful** intermediate operation.

Definition of stateful from [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> Stateful operations, such as distinct and sorted, may **incorporate state from previously seen elements** when processing new elements.
> Stateful operations **may** need to process the **entire** input before
> producing a result. For example, one cannot produce any results from
> sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream. As a
> result, under parallel computation, some pipelines containing stateful
> intermediate operations **may require multiple passes on the data or may
> need to buffer significant data**. Pipelines containing exclusively
> stateless intermediate operations can be processed in a single pass,
> whether sequential or parallel, with minimal data buffering.

How is `default Stream<T> takeWhile​(Predicate<? super T> predicate)` stateful?It does not need look at the entire input, etc...

It's almost like `filter` but short-circuiting.

Comment: I think the excerpt you are quoting is incomplete. The section immediately preceding the section you are quoting, provides the definition: "Stateful operations, such as `distinct` and `sorted`, may incorporate state from previously seen elements when processing new elements". So a *stateful operation* is the processing of an element which **depends on other elements**.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, seems like a crucial point

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, `takeWhile` should process the longest prefix of the `Stream` that satisfies the given `Predicate`. This means that in order to know if a given element of the `Stream` should be processed by `takeWhile`, you may have to process all the elements preceding it.

Hence, you need to know the state of the processing of the previous elements of the `Stream` in order to know how to process the current element.

In sequential `Stream`s you don't have to keep state, since once you reach the first element that doesn't match the `Predicate`, you know you are done.

In parallel `Stream`s, however, this becomes much trickier.

Comment: This sounds a bit tricky, but how is `takeWhile` different from `filter` beside the fact that it ends the pipeline the fist time it encounters an element that fails the test? I don't see why it'd need to remember state related to preceding elements. And running `Arrays.stream(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,0}).takeWhile(i -> {System.out.println("testing " + i);return i < 0;}).forEach(System.out::println)` only prints `testing 1` (implying that it indeed drops the stream when the first test failure occurs)

Comment: @ernest_k for sequential streams it would be very similar to filter, but for parallel streams not.

Comment: @Eran that's a very valid point which escaped me. Thank you!

Comment: @Hulk not sure what you're getting to. It simply doesn't do anything with elements after the first failure, and that doesn't determine the result, it's just like `limit` with a predicate instead of a number.

Comment: @ernest_k yes, see my answer - it is indeed very similar to `limit`, which is also stateful for similar reasons. My comment was adressing your concrete example - that the predicate is not evaluated (i.e. nothing is printed) does not show that the operation does "nothing", it just means it decides to not emit an element to the next stage based on its internal state, without evaluating the predicate.

Answer (score 7):

It is stateful in that it changes its behavior based on internal state (whether it has already seen an element matching the predicate). It does not process elements independently from each other. This may disable certain optimizations and may reduce the usefulness of processing in parallel.

So it is stateful in the same way [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)) and [`skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip(long)) are stateful - the outcome does not (only) depend on the current element, but also on elements preceding it.